# Raspberry Pi sending a file to Windows 11 via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, windows, data-transfer

My goal is to send an image from a Raspberry Pi 4 to a Windows 10 / Windows 11 machine using bluetooth and OBEX.

So far I can pair the two devices but the Windows machine sees the Pi as an audio device only.  Doing a 'sdptool browse' shows lots of bluetooth services being run on the Windows machine, but neither 'FTP' nor 'OBEX' appear (which I believe are essential to a successful transferance).

I'm pretty new at this so apologies if this question sounds uninformed. :-)

Comment: I think you need to start `obexd` or the RPi. There is more information in the following answer: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114187/121848

Comment: Why bluetooth when ssh/scp is several orders of magnitude easier.